# Algorithmically fit triangle into box

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

[image: triangle in box]

Let's say we have a triangle of known edge lengths a, b, and c, within a square box of known size l. The triangle fits "exactly" in the box, with each corner contacting the side of the box. Two corners of the triangle may contact the same side of the box. If we know the "general orientation" of the triangle in the box (ie. which one of the four possible solutions we have), how can we **algorithmically** determine the exact position and orientation of the triangle?

We have as algorithmic inputs l, the length of the box size, [a b c] being the sides lengths of the triangle and theta`, the estimate of the orientation. We want as an output x and y representing the position within the box, and theta, the bearing orientation within the box.

Specifically, we'll define the position to be where the perpendicular bisector and edge meet, and the angle that line (orange) makes with the vertical.

Follow up: how could we do this if the fit was not exact?

I understand how to get the position if given the orientation, and the orientation given the position, but how to determine both is evading me.

Comment: there are multiple ways of placing such triangle, so you cannot determine exact, you can pick one

Comment: Infinite? My geometric intuition would say 4, as we're constrained by the corners always touching the sides.

Comment: i was wrong about infinite, but definitely multiple - consider mirroring

Comment: Yes, hence we have the constraint we know the "general orientation" of the object, lets say +-10 degrees, but not exact

Comment: what is general orientation?

Comment: We have a guess of the orientation, but not the exact value. This is how we'd distinguish between the valid solutions

Answer (score 0):

If the triangle "fits exactly", then there are only two kinds of things that can constrain the triangle's orientation:

1. One (sufficiently long) side of the triangle is jammed against opposite sides of the box, as in your diagram.  In this case you can use acos() to calculate its 4 possible orientations; or
2. One side of the triangle is lying along a side of the box, in which case its orientation is vertical or horizontal.

There are a small total number of possibilities per triangle -- at most 48.  So you can just test them all or pick one given that "general orientation"